# 4TB drives in RAID 1 with Promise SuperTrak EX8350

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, gpt, capacity

Two 4TB drives are connected to a Promise SuperTrak EX8350 controller with the intention of setting-up a RAID 1 array. Before attempting to create any logical drives, the capacities of both drives show up as 2199.02 GB (in the Promise Array Manager utility). Is it possible to configure/update the Promise SuperTrak EX8350 so as to be able to use 4TB drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation's FAQ states the following:

What it the maximum disk drive storage capacity of SuperTrak EX Series?
The SuperTrak EX8300 and EX8350 support up to 3.2 TB (eight 400 GB
disk drives).

A later version of the FAQ states:

The SuperTrak EX8300 and EX8350 support up to 6.0 TB (eight 750 GB
physical drives).

I guess when they wrote the docs they only conceived of these drive sizes.  I'm fairly certain that if the utility only allows you 2.2TB access that is all you are getting.  I've done this before as well.  I bought a 3 or 4TB HDD just to find out the [Dell] RAID controller would only recognize 2TB.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q:**What it the maximum physical drive storage capacity of SuperTrak EX 
>   Series?
>
> **A:**The SuperTrak EX8300 and EX8350 support up to 6.0 TB (eight 750 GB 
>   physical drives).

from the FAQ in [the user manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/110745238/1-SuperTrak-EX8300-8350-User-v2-0).